# Bash: Complex examples of sed command

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I have a file which looks like so which has 2 column (space-delimited):

```
chr1.21.imputed_info:1   100880328
chr1.31.imputed_info:1   10566215
chr1.23.imputed_info:--- 110198129
chr1.23.imputed_info:--- 114445880
chr1.24.imputed_info:--- 118141492
chr1.25.imputed_info:--- 120257110
chr1.25.imputed_info:1   121280613
chr1.30.imputed_info:--- 121287994
chr1.30.imputed_info:--- 145604302
```

I want to extract the number following "chr" which goes from 1-22 and the second column. So my output would look like so:

```
    1 100880328
    1 10566215
    1 110198129
    1 114445880
    1 118141492
    1 120257110
    1 121280613
    1 121287994
    1 145604302
```

A few important considerations:

- As I said, the number right after "chr" goes from 1-22 so it could chr1, chr2 ... chr22.
- The number following chr1,chr2 etc could go over up to 50. So you could have chr1.50 for example, or chr2.45 etc
- The "info:" part at the end of the column1 may look like info:1, info:2.. info:22 OR info:---

I have come up with this in Bash:

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/chr//g' | sed 's/.imputed_info://g'
```

This gets me very close but it does this:

```
1.211    100880328
1.31     10566215
1.23---  110198129
1.23---  114445880
1.24---  118141492
1.25---  120257110
1.251    121280613
1.25---  121287994
1.30---  145604302
1.301    149906413
```

I know there would be ways to do this in R and Python but I should say this is a huge file so going through Bash would a great time saver.. So if anyone has a nice (and ideally clean solution - I do realise my sed command is kinda ugly) it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What is about leading spaces in expected output?

Comment: You don't really need two `sed` commands for this. Maybe try `awk -F'[a-z. -]+' '{print $2,$6}' file.txt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shorter way:

```
sed 's/^chr//;s/\..* / /' filename
```

**EDIT:**
Translation: remove the leading "chr" (if it's there), and replace everything from the first '.' to the last space (that is, a '.' followed by anything, followed by ' ') with a single space.

Answer (score 3):

`sed 's/chr\([0-9]*\)[^ ]*[ ]*\([0-9]*\)/\1\t\2/' file.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[. ]' '{print substr($1,4), $NF}' file.txt
```

That splits each line by dot or space and prints the first field, starting from the 4th character and the last field. (`NF` is the number of fields, `$NF` is the last field)

Output:

```
1 100880328
1 10566215
1 110198129
1 114445880
1 118141492
1 120257110
1 121280613
1 121287994
1 145604302
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Short way:

```
sed 's/chr\([^.]*\).* /\1 /' file
```

---

Using `sed` with all conditions applied:

```
sed 's/^chr\(1[1-9]\{0,1\}\|10\|2[012]\)\.\(1[1-9]\{0,1\}\|10\|[234][0-9]\|50\)[^ ]*  *\([^ ]*\)/\1 \3/' file
```

Using `sed` following syntax only:

```
sed 's/^chr\([1-9][1-9]*\)\.[1-9][1-9]*[^ ]*  *\([^ ]*\)/\1 \2/' file
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
/^chr([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+/{
    match($1, /[0-9]+/);
    $1 = substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH);
    print;
}' file
```

Output:

```
1 100880328
1 10566215
1 110198129
1 114445880
1 118141492
1 120257110
1 121280613
1 121287994
1 145604302
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have sed with extended regex:

```
sed -r -n 's/chr(2[0-2]|1?[0-9])\..+\s([0-9]+)/\1 \2/p' file.txt
```

If the number after `chr` can not be higher than 22, you can simplify (without extended regex) the expression to

```
sed -r 's/chr([0-9]+)\..+\s([0-9]+)/\1 \2/' file.txt
```

**Regex explained**

- `chr` - literal match
- `(2[0-2]|1?[0-9])` - first matching group

  - `2[0-2]` - 20 to 22
  - `|` or (if it is not 20-22, test the next expression in group)
  - `1?` - zero or one `1`
  - `[0-9]` - 0-9
- `\.` - literal dot
- `.+\s` - one or more characters followed by a space character
- `([0-9]+)` - second matching group, matching one or more digits
- `/\1 \2/` - replace with first and second matching group

**Result**

I extended your example to

```
chr1.21.imputed_info:1   100880328
chr2.31.imputed_info:1   10566215
chr11.23.imputed_info:--- 110198129
chr12.23.imputed_info:--- 114445880
chr22.24.imputed_info:--- 118141492
chr1.25.imputed_info:--- 120257110
chr1.25.imputed_info:1   121280613
chr1.30.imputed_info:--- 121287994
chr1.30.imputed_info:--- 145604302
```

Output from `sed` is:

```
1 100880328
2 10566215
11 110198129
12 114445880
22 118141492
1 120257110
1 121280613
1 121287994
1 145604302
```